# Cannot bring data fro a URL using httpost request Android

Tags: java, android, http-post

I am having serious trouble on fetching my data from the server.

My url is this:

```
server_url = http://serverurl/_all
```

If I call that from my browser, I can see the data being printed. So I guess it has to do with how I make the request. I have used that part of code before, when making a post request for example in a php file. But now my server is setup differently and I know that the server works fine because I can fetch my data in the browser and in an IOS app.

I have tried this:

```
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URLEncoder.encode(server_url));
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(server_url);
    //httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
}
// convert response to string
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    result = sb.toString();
    System.out.println("Result:" + result);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}
```

and I get this:

```
Result : Error 404 not found
```

Then, searching on the SO I have tried the following:

- Remove the http://
- change the HttpPost line into  this

  **HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URLEncoder.encode(server_url));**

In this case I get this error:

```
12-01 21:41:11.772: E/log_tag(28340): Error in http connection java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=http://ec2-54-194-95-194.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/backend2/index.php/skicenter/_all
12-01 21:41:11.772: E/log_tag(28340): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
12-01 21:41:11.772: E/log_tag(28340): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

There should be something wrong with the **_** character os something else that I am missing.

Can you help me on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure, you are using the correct HTTP verb for the request? Maybe it's a `GET` request and you are trying with `POST`.